# ¿Por qué mi clase de conexión a base de datos en PHP no consulta la base de datos?

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Database {
    public static $db;
    public static $con;


     function Database(){
        $this->user = "phpmyadmin";
        $this->pass = "1234";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->ddbb = "zroad";
     }
     function connect(){
        $con = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->ddbb);
        if ($con->connect_error){
            Module::$message = "Invalidad la conexión a la <b>Base de Datos</b>";
            Module::Error();
        }
     }
     public static function getCon(){
        if (self::$con == null && self::$db == null){
            self::$db   = new Database();
            self::$con  = self::$db->connect();
        }
        return self::$con;
     }
     public static function doit($sql){ 
        $conex = self::getCon();
        return $conex->query($sql);     
     }
     public static function one($query, $aclass){
        $cnt    = 0;
        $fount  = null;
        $data   = new $aclass;
        while ($r = $query->fetch_array()){
            $cnt = 1;
            foreach ($r as $key -> $v){
                if ($cnt > 0 && $cnt %2 == 0){
                    $data->$key = $v;
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
            $found = $data;
            break;
        }
        return $found;
     }

}//EOF Database.php
?>
y el index.php que llama a las funciones es:
    <?php

include "core/autoload.php";

define ("ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));

$md = new Lb();
$md->loadModule("index");

echo Module::$module;

$sql = "INSERT INTO contenidos (titulo, tipo, contenido, categoria, alias) VALUES ( 'dominicana', 'pagina', 'todo', 'musica', 'mike')";

        $query = Database::doit($sql);


?>
```

Comment: Aja pero.... te muestra algún error? ya validaste el tipo de dato que estas insertando? si esta corriendo tu mysql?

Comment: debes decirnos que has intentado y que fallo te está dando... no creas que con leer codigo ya se puede resolver

Comment: Tu `Clase` es algo deficiente... no lo digo para desanimarte, sino para que la mejores. Por ejemplo aquí, llamas `$conex->query($sql)`... pero la clase no está dotada de un método `query`. En Github hay varias clases que están más o menos bien hechas para gestionar la conexión y consultas mediante mysqli. [Por ejemplo esta](https://github.com/aaronlord/mysqli/blob/master/database/Mysqli_Database.php). Creo que te podrías inspirar en alguna de ellas para construir tu propia clase de forma adecuada.

Comment: ok, probe la consulta directamente en phpmyadmin y tambien con una conexion ordinaria haciendo $variable = mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $bd) y luego consultando con $variable->query($sql) y funciona por lo que me di cuenta que el formato de la consulta esta correcto, pero cuando hago lo mismo con la funcion doit()  crea la conexión pero no realiza los resultados indicados que seria ingresar los datos a la base de datos

Comment: La clase no tiene un método `query`, por lo tanto no funcionará.

Comment: @A.Cedano `$conex` es una conexión MySQLi, que tiene un método `query`. No importa que no exista en la clase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es algo realmente simple y lo puedes encontrar aquí:

```
function connect(){
    $con = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->ddbb);
    if ($con->connect_error){
        Module::$message = "Invalidad la conexión a la <b>Base de Datos</b>";
        Module::Error();
    }
}
```

En el método `connect` creas una conexión a la base de datos con MySQLi... ¡pero nunca lo devuelves! Entonces `self::$con` será null en el método `getCon` y `$conex->query` fallará en `doit` porque `$conex` es null.

La solución: devuelve `$con` y ya funciona:

```
function connect(){
    $con = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->ddbb);
    if ($con->connect_error){
        Module::$message = "Invalidad la conexión a la <b>Base de Datos</b>";
        Module::Error();
    }
    return $con;
}
```

Después de hacer ese cambio, probé en local (quitando algunas partes para que no fallase) y funcionó sin problemas, insertando en la base de datos.